# skip a folder while doing build in webpack and angular cli

Tags: webpack, angular-cli

I have a folder called mockData inside of assets folder. This is required only for developers and local environment. For my next environments it is not required. How do i skip this folder from getting bundled when doing a build? Is there any webpack/angularcli config what i can do?

Below is my .angular-cli.json file

```
{
    "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
    "project": {
        "name": "myProj"
    },
    "apps": [{
        "root": "src",
        "outDir": "dist",
        "assets": [
            "assets",
            "favicon.ico"
        ],
        "index": "index.html",
        "main": "main.ts",
        "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
        "test": "test.ts",
        "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
        "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
        "prefix": "app",
        "styles": [
            "styles.styl"
        ],
        "scripts": [],
        "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
        "environments": {
            "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
            "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
        }
    }],
    "e2e": {
        "protractor": {
            "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
        }
    },
    "lint": [{
            "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json"
        },
        {
            "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
        },
        {
            "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
        }
    ],
    "test": {
        "karma": {
            "config": "./karma.conf.js"
        }
    },
    "defaults": {
        "styleExt": "styl",
        "component": {}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude directories in your webpack.config file:

```
{
    test: /\.ts$/,
    use: { *** whatever loaders *** },
    exclude: /assets/mockData/
}
```

In Angular cli, you would add this to your `.angular-cli.json` file

```
"test": {
  "codeCoverage": {
    "exclude": [
      "**/assets/mockData"
    ]
  },
  ...
}
```

Or exclude the files in your tsconfig.json file

```
"exclude": [
    "**/assets/mockData"
]
```

Comment: Any idea of how to exclude in angularcli??

Comment: Tried it. But does not seem to skip the folder.

Comment: Add your webpack.config file (the entire file) to your question.

Comment: i use basic angular cli installation file.

Comment: Depending on the version, or if you're using a seed project there may be differences in this file - it's hard to troubleshoot yours without seeing the actual file you're using.